# Replacing double backwards slashes with single ones in c#

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I need to replace double quotes with single so that something like this

```
\\\\servername\\dir1\\subdir1\\
```

becomes

```
\\servername\dir1\subdir1\
```

I tried this

```
string dir = "\\\\servername\\dir1\\subdir1\\";
string s = dir.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

The result I get is

```
\\servername\\dir1\\subdir1\\
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see result in dubugger?

Comment: To get them as literal, you should use the `@` symbol. string dir = @"\\servername\dir1\subdir1\";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to replace anything here. The backslashes are escaped, that's why they are doubled.
Just like `\t` represents a tabulator, `\\` represents a single `\`. You can see the full list of *Escape Sequences* [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

```
string dir = "\\\\servername\\dir1\\subdir1\\";
Console.WriteLine(dir);
```

This will output `\\servername\dir1\subdir1\`.

BTW: You can use the verbatim string to make it more readable:

```
string dir = @"\\servername\dir1\subdir1\";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the code for replacing. The result that you get is:

```
\servername\dir1\subdir1\
```

When you are looking at the result in the debugger, it's shown as it would be written as a literal string, so a backslash characters is shown as two backslash characters.

The string that you create isn't what you think it is. This code:

```
string dir = "\\\\servername\\dir1\\subdir1\\";
```

produces a string containing:

```
\\servername\dir1\subdir1\
```

The replacement code does replace the `\\` at the beginning of the string.

If you want to produce the string `\\\\servername\\dir1\\subdir1\\`, you use:

```
string dir = @"\\\\servername\\dir1\\subdir1\\";
```

or:

```
string dir = "\\\\\\\\servername\\\\dir1\\\\subdir1\\\\";
```

Comment: but why is the result '\\a\\b\\c' not '\\\\a\\b\\c' (allowing for the debugger doubling up all \. The result should not be symetric , there should be different number of \ at the front since we started with more

Comment: @pm100: We start out with double backslashes only at the start of the string, so that's the only ones that gets replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This string `"\\\\servername\\dir1\\subdir1\\"` is the same as `@"\\servername\dir1\subdir1\"`. In order to escape backslashes you need either use `@` symbol before string, or use double backslash instead of one.

*Why you need that?* Because in C# backslash used for [escape sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).