# vb filepath getter code gets different filepath then C# getter code

Tags: c#, vb.net, filepath

I am converting a vb website app to C# and some of the conversions are producing weird results for example

```
Dim holidayfilepath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/USA_Holidays.txt")
Dim sList As New List(Of Date)
sList = GetHolidays(holidayfilepath)
Dim s As String = sList.Aggregate("", Function(current, dDate) current & dDate.ToString())
```

returns the filepath variable as

```
"X:\Folder\Toolkit\Toolkit\Content\USA_Holidays.txt"
```

and the code snippet works as expected, producing a list of dates as strings.

But the C# version

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var holidayfilepath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/USA_Holidays.txt");            
        var sList = new List<DateTime>();
        sList = DayCalcs.GetHolidays(holidayfilepath);
        var s = sList.Aggregate("", (current, dDate) => current + dDate.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

        return View(s);
    }
```

returns the holidayfilepath variable as

```
"X:\\Folder\\Toolkit\\Toolkit\\Content\\USA_Holidays.txt"
```

which produces an exception.

Is there a reason the same code line produces a different result in C#? Why does the C# version insert double backslashes which is causing the error?

It produces a TypeInitializationException
InnerException

```
{"Could not find a part of the path 'X:\\Folder\\Toolkit\\Toolkit\\DataFiles\\Holidays.txt'."}
```

Isn't that what the variable call is supposed to do? get the correct file path, Its finding some folder DataFiles? Since the error is occurring when calling GetHolidays, here is that code snippett

```
 public static List<DateTime> GetHolidays(string holidaysFile)
    {
        var sAllDates = File.ReadAllLines(holidaysFile);
        return sAllDates.Select(Convert.ToDateTime).ToList();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Well the exception said it was looking for DataFiles/Holidays.txt, absolutely zero clue why, but I changed the folder and filename and now it works. Incredibly strange. That text file and folder, with their original names were created in this solution using the add new item dropdown so where that exception is coming from is beyond my understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing double backwards slashes with single ones in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482450/replacing-double-backwards-slashes-with-single-ones-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that, of course I could replace the double backsplash, the questions is why is the vb producing a different string than the exact same code line in C#

Comment: The exception has a different string than what you say `holidayfilepath` is.  Do you also have the stacktrace? It looks like the error isn't coming from `DayCalcs.GetHolidays(holidayfilepath);` from the `Index` action or `holidayfilepath` isn't what you have in the question.

Comment: @dinotom What does `DayCalcs.GetHolidays()` do internally?

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, strings are more literal and there isn't the need to escape the backslashes. In C#, the backslash is an escape character, so it has to be escaped by itself.

You should try something like:

```
var holidayfilepath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/USA_Holidays.txt"); 
var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(holidayfilepath);           
var sList = new List<DateTime>();
sList = DayCalcs.GetHolidays(fullpath);
```

Comment: The backslashes arent causing the issue, {"Could not find a part of the path 'X:\\Folder\\Toolkit\\Toolkit\\DataFiles\\Holidays.txt'."}  Where is it finding this DataFiles folder? there is no folder in the solution with that name.